# Octopus deploy on Mac OS runner from teamcity

Tags: macos, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I'm setting up a build on Teamcity that will build a XCode project, then create a release in Octopus and using Powershell copy the files into a server. However, I'm having an issue, while both steps (Teamcity and Octopus) work independently, currently Teamcity is telling me that my build agent does not complies with the requirement 'OctopusDeploy: Release'.

I've downloaded the plugin [that is here](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/TeamCity), and have managed to put the zip file on the runner directory, and while Octopus restarted and seems to have installed it, it still doesn't show as one of the available Build runners.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't do this, or that's what it seems like. Installing the plugin on a fresh install of Teamcity ignored the Mac build agent, which means it's not compatible.

This makes sense because Octopus uses an exe wrapper so this could be the reason. If anybody finds something else, feel free to contribute.